# Integrate spring projects and EJB projects within a gradle(or maven) multiple projects

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle, ejb

I have a gradle multiple projects. The structure is like below:

```
|--MyProject
|  |--ejb-project
|  |  --build.gradle
|  |--spring-project
|     --com.mine.demo
   |    --Test.java
|  |  --build.gradle
|  |--build.gradle
|  |--settings.gradle
```

in the settings.gradle

```
include: ':ejb-project'
include: ':spring-project'
```

I defined a **Test.java** in the spring-project.

**Now**, if I wanna use **Test.java** in the EJB projects, How can I use it? Are there configurations to be configured?

Questions can be simplfy as this: **Can I use a class from spring project in a ejb project within a gradle(or maven) multiple projects? If can, How can I use it?**

I've never done this before, so barely know how to integrate spring in ejb. HELP!

Comment: Yes, it is possible I guess. Read here : https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/ejb.html